# Как реагировать на неподобающие комментарии?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, нормы-поведения

Зайдя посмотреть новые вопросы я столкнулся с вопросами (там несколько вопросов подряд с интересными комментариями и с одними и теми же комментаторами)

[image: очень интересные комментарии]

Конкретно этот скриншот я сделал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475748). Соответствует ли это нормам поведения на площадке? Как реагировать?

Comment: Нет, не считается. Это не профессионально и не be-nice. Смело отмечайте такие случаи тревогой.

Comment: Непонятно о чем именно ваш вопрос. Вам не понравилось что конкретно? Потрудитесь пожалуйста более внятно формулировать свои мысли. Пока-что голосую за закрытие.

Comment: @Kromster Выше мне был дан ответ, не вижу смысла давать больше конкретики.

Comment: Окей, раз такой ответ, то поправил вопрос под него.